# How to create a debounce-like function using variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, debouncing

I have a component in React that essentially **autosaves form input** 3 seconds after the user's last keystroke. There are possibly dozens of these components rendered on my webpage at a time.

I have tried using debounce from Lodash, but that did not seem to work (or I implemented it poorly). Instead, I am using a function that compares a local variable against a global variable to determine the most recent function call.

Curiously, this code seems to work in JSFiddle. However, it does not work on my Desktop.

Specifically, `globalEditIndex` seems to retain its older values even after the delay. As a result, if a user makes 5 keystrokes, the `console.log` statement runs 5 times instead of 1.

Could someone please help me figure out why?

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import {func1, func2} from "../actions";

// A component with some JSX form elements. This component shows up dozens of times on a single page
const MyComponent = (props) => {

    // Used to store the form's state for Redux
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});
    
    // Global variable that keeps track of number of keystrokes
    let globalEditIndex = 0;
    
    // This function is called whenever a form input is changed (onchange)
    const editHandler = (e) => {
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            e.target.name: e.target.value,
        });

        autosaveHandler();
    }
    
    const autosaveHandler = () => {
        globalEditIndex++;
        let localEditIndex = globalEditIndex;
        setTimeout(() => {

            // Ideally, subsequent function calls increment globalEditIndex, 
            // causing earlier function calls to evaluate this expression as false.
            if (localEditIndex === globalEditIndex) {
                console.log("After save: " +globalEditIndex);
                globalEditIndex = 0;
            }

        }, 3000);
    }

    return(
        // JSX code here
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    prop1: state.prop1,
    prop2: state.prop2
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, { func1, func2 }
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, basically you just want to debounce form's input value, correct? This can be easily handled with a proper custom hook.

Comment: You did imported useRef from react, but what stopped you from using it `const globalEditIndexRef = useRef(0);` and then `globalEditIndexRef.current++`, `let localEditIndex = globalEditIndexRef.current;` and etc? In your function your variables are closure-captured, in setTimeout callback - they are still same closure-captured

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270521/8690857 Or are you trying to create *some* globally debounced handler? It is unclear what you mean exactly by "There are possibly dozens of these components rendered on my webpage at a time." Are you trying to collectively debounce *all* of them? Are they all rendered to the DOM and/or interacted with simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I was typing up answer on how I solved this previously in my own projects before I read @DrewReese's comment - that seems like a way better implementation than what I did, and I will be using that myself going forward. Check out his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270521/8690857

---

I think you hit it on the head in your question - you are probably trying to implement debounce wrong. You should debounce your `formState` value to whatever delay you want to put on autosaving (if I'm assuming the code correctly).

An example custom hook I've used in the past looks like this:

```
export const useDebounce = <T>(value: T, delay: number) => {
    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, [value]);

    return debouncedValue;
};

// Without typings
const useDebounce = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
};
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState<number>(0);

  const debouncedValue = useDebounce<number>(myValue, 3000);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Debounced value: ", debouncedValue);
  }, [debouncedFormState]);

  // without typings
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(0);

  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(myValue, 3000);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Debounced value: ", debouncedValue);
  }, [debouncedFormState]);
```

For demonstration purposes I've made a CodeSandbox demonstrating this `useDebounce` function with your forms example. You can view it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wilson-cjl85v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This works well, but I find that whenever I perform a state update with Redux, the component _constantly_ fires the debounce function. Why might this be?