# how useEffect clearup function works in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

My idea was when user types the email in the input box when stops for 500  milliseconds that time only useEffects side effect will run other wise user continusly types side effects will not run that will clear with help of  cleanUp function. side effects runs frist time when the app starts. After that any dependency changed cleanup function runs therafter  side effects runs. so if i create setTimeout function in the side effects with 500 milliseconds and I clear the timeout function in the cleanup function it will clear the side effect. But when user stops typing in the input box in that time also dependency changed clenup function need to  clear the side effects. But cleanup function runs properly but not clear the side effects side effects also runs how it possible? why cleanup function not clear the side effects in the user stop typing

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
    setFormIsValid(
      enteredEmail.includes("@") && enteredPassword.trim().length > 6
    );
    console.log("side effect");
  }, 500);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
    console.log("cleanUp function");
  };
}, [enteredEmail, enteredPassword]);
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70269424/8690857

Comment: The problem is that the useEffect hook does not track the actual time that has passed, it only tracks whether the dependencies have changed.

Comment: You need to create the timeout outside of your effect. Otherwise you create a new timeout everytime the user is typing.

Comment: your problem will be solved using the concept of debouncing. refer link to learn how it work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJhA0DrH5co&ab_channel=AkshaySaini